# How to use header to post row from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do you search and display results where userid = bookid? The **bookids** are a foreign key while **userid** is a primary key in two different tables. This is implemented with MVC and using PDO. How do I pass a parameter from the view to controller to model to query where `SELECT * FROM user,Book WHERE user_id=Book_id`

**View:**

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']))
{
    exit;
}
$user_id=$_GET['id'];
?>

<div id="BookItem">
    <div id = "thumbview_Book_title">
        Books
    </div>
<?php 
    $BookArray = $this->_dispResult['book'];
    $num = count($BookArray);

    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
    {
        $row = $BookArray[$i];
    }
    <img src="<?php echo $row['booksrcpath'];?>">
    <?php echo $row['bookName'];?>
```

**Controller:**

```
$bookId= isset($_GET["id"])?$_GET["id"]:'';

    if($bookId)
    {
        $result['bookbyuserid']=$this->_userModel->getBookByUserId();
        $BookRow = $this->_bookModel->getbookById($bookId);
        if(!$bookRow)
        {
            gotoUrl('/error/?error=lost');
            exit;
        }
    }

    $result['book_row'] = $bookRow;
    $result['book_array'] = $this->_bookModel->getAllBooks($bookId, $bookRow['username']);

    $this->_showPage('books', 'books.php',$result);          
}
```

#### Model

Model from two tables query from user table and book table selecting all books where the bookid is equal to userid. It's basically the same as `SELECT *FROM USER, BOOK WHERE BOOK_ID = USER_ID`.

```
public function getBookByUserId()
{
    $BookByUserIdArray = array();
    $this->setTable('book,user');

    $select = 'user.username,user.id as user_id,    //$select = string to search db
      book.id as book_id,book.book_name';

    $where ="user.id=book.user_id";   //string to search where in db
    $result= $this->query($select, $where); //query db
    while($Result && $row =$this->nextRow() )   
    {
        $user_name = $row['username'];
        $book_id = $row['book_id'];
        if($this->_BookImgSr->getBookUrl($user_name, $book_id))    // folder where image files are found and searched from
        {
            $row['user_photo'] = $this->_BookImgSr->getUserPhoto($user_name);
            $row['Book_path'] = $this->_BookImgSr->getBookPath($user_name, $Book_id);
            array_push( $BookByUserIdArray, $row);
        }
    } 

    return  $BookByUserIdArray;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just fixed the edit at the top how to pass the parameter

Answer (score 2):

> How do I pass parameter from the view to controller to model to query

That's the wrong path.
Nothing has to be passed *from* the view.
A controller has to call a model, get the data, and then pass it to a view.

So, here you go:
First, calling a model to get the data

```
$bookId= isset($_GET["id"])?$_GET["id"]:'';
$BookRow = $this->_bookModel->getbookById($bookId);
```

and finally, calling a view:

```
$this->_showPage('books', 'books.php',$result);
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for that